Flutter get Locale from RevenueCat
I am (happily) using RevenueCat, everything is working perfectly fine.
BUT now I would love to get the users locale, or more specific, the users AppStore locale.
Is there any way to get this from RevenueCat ? The closest I found is:

StoreProduct.currencyCode

I also found that for iOS 13+:
import StoreKit

let country = SKPaymentQueue.default().storefront?.countryCode

Sad enough I didn't find a Flutter way of doing this.
Is there any solution for this? Let me know if you need any more information.

You could use the in_app_purchase package and only use it to check country code.
import 'package:in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase.dart';

Future<String> countryCode() => InAppPurchase.instance.countryCode();

Otherwise you could write your own plugin https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages

yes! I think that is what I needed.
FYI: Apple is returning alpha-3 codes, Android apha-2.
